# How to describe this factory by UML class diagram?

Tags: factory-pattern

In my work i have a lot of discrepancy of opinions about UMLing class diagram of this sample factory:

```
class Program
{
    private static TrainComponentsData _trainComponentsData;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitTrainComponentsData();
        string str = _trainComponentsData.ToString();
    }

    private static void InitTrainComponentsData()
    {
        ITrainComponentsReader reader = TrainComponentsReaderFactory.Create("XML");
        _trainComponentsData = reader.Read();
    }
}

public class TrainComponentsReaderFactory
{
    internal static ITrainComponentsReader Create(string readerType)
    {
       //....
    }
}

internal class XMLTrainComponentsReader : ITrainComponentsReader
{
   //....
}

public class TrainComponentsData
{
   //....
}

internal interface ITrainComponentsReader
{
    TrainComponentsData Read();
}
```

i just a little confused about various of difference diagrams:

[image: UML class diagram 1 from internet]
[image: UML class diagram 2 from internet]
[image: UML class diagram 3 from internet]

etc...

thanks!